# How to use NOT use "this" keyword in java in this JOGL scenario

Tags: java, this, jogl

1) The code at the bottom is part of a introduction to JOGL which is just openGL for java and I can't quite understand the usage of "this" here. I have used it before and researched it point to point in many uses but I don't understand how its used in **this particular context**, so please don't direct me to another "this" explanation as I've read them already.

For example, below, the bit that is:

```
public S1_original() {
        super("S1");
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

What is the "this" keyword referring to here? I didn't write any other classes, so what is it using ".setSize()" method to?

2) If I were to NOT use "this" in the example above with "this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT) what would I put there?

3) What is "this" referring to in this code then?

```
canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
```

Why did similar lines need a "this" before it but here its using this inside as a parameter.

```
public class S1_original extends Frame implements GLEventListener {

  private static final int WIDTH=640;
  private static final int HEIGHT=480;
  //private static final float NEAR_CLIP=0.1f;
  //private static final float FAR_CLIP=100.0f;    

  private GLCanvas canvas;
  private FPSAnimator animator;
  private double theta = 0;
  private double sinValue = 0;
  private double cosValue = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    S1 frame = new S1();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public S1_original() {
    super("S1");
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
    GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

    this.add(canvas, "Center");        
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    } );

    canvas.addGLEventListener(this);

    animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);

    animator.start();
  }
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: JOGL is mainly a Java binding for the OpenGL & OpenGL ES APIs. It's not just OpenGL for Java, it contains its own cross-platform native windowing toolkit (NEWT), it supports Oculus Rift, it contains some helpers to ease the use of some OpenGL "entities" (typically for images, textures, fixed pipeline emulation, ...). The code you quote is very bad, using the same class to extend a container and to implement GLEventListener is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

This *is* a completely standard use of `this`: it refers to the object the method is currently operating on. Since `S1_original()` is a constructor, it refers to the object currently being constructed. So what that line does is to call `setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)` on the object being constructed. However, `this` can always be omitted when calling a member method from inside another member method or constructor, so the line is equivalent to simply:

```
setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Your confusion probably stems from the fact that you haven't actually created a `setSize` method in your class. However, note that your class extends `Frame` - the method is inherited from that class.

Comment: Ok if I don't use "this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)" what do I use instead of the "this" in front? I want to know to be able to understand, because I'm still confused which object its referring to, how else would I write that line without utilizing this and directly typing the object?

Comment: `this` or nothing.  It's referring to a method on itself.  You can leave `this` off of 99.9% of places you see it without altering what the code does.  In this case, `super.setSize(...)` is also valid.

Comment: Maybe my confusion is coming from what I failed to read up before but I don't know what I'm missing - I didn't know you could just put a method name by itself and have it affect another object? E.g. if there is an object that is a number, I have a method that multiplies numbers by two, I can do the object.multiplyTwo() for example and it multiplies that object.

Comment: If you just put a method name by itself (as a part of the code of some method), it will affect _this_ object - that is, the one the containing method is currently running on. `S1_original()` is the constructor of the `S1_original` class, so it will run whenever a new `S1_original` object is being constructed, and if you call `setSize` with `this.` or nothing in front, it will run on the particular `S1_original` object that is in the process of being created.

Comment: (So you're right about (non-`static`) methods needing to have an object to execute on, but precisely for that reason, as long as you are inside a non-`static` method, you know that whenever that method is executing, it _is_ executing on some object. The entire point of `this` is to refer to that object, and in most cases, you can omit `this` and get that object by default.)

Comment: Ok thank you, the first part is clear now. A little confused about non-static methods still - you mean invoking a method without an object is ok to do aside from within non-static methods? So I can't use "setSize()" inside a non-static method? If so why is that and how would I make it static?

Comment: You're not invoking it without an object - a non-static method _can't_ be invoked without an object. However, you don't have to _specify_ the object; it's _implicitly_ `this` if you don't say anything else. From the inside of a static method, there is no `this` because static methods _can only_ be invoked without an object, so if you want to call a non-static method from a static one, you need to specify an object.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the "this" keyword referring to here? I didn't write any other classes, so what is it using ".setSize()" method to?

The `this` keyword represents a reference to the object on which the method is being run.  That might be an instance of the class in which the code appears, or an instance of a subclass.  The semantics are the same as if `this` were replaced with an ordinary variable containing a reference to the same object.

> If I were to NOT use "this" in the example above with "this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT) what would I put there?

Nothing.  You would just write `setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)`.  It means exactly the same thing.

When you see a method invoked on `this`, it is ordinarily for code clarity, to emphasize that the method is invoked on **this** object, as opposed to on a different one that is available.  For example, I tend to do that in `equals()` methods, where I am invoking the same methods two different objects, one of them `this`, and comparing the results.

I have known people who liked to use `this` to distinguish from `super`.  It is never necessary to do so, and I squash such behavior when I find it because it can be confusing.  The risk is too great that it will be taken as "this class", whereas it really means "this object".  Getting that wrong may lead a reader to suppose that a different method is being invoked than actually is the case.

> What is "this" referring to in this code then?
>
> ```
> canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
> ```

The `this` means the same thing there as anywhere else.  It refers to the object on which the method containing that code is running.  If you consider that object as an actor performing the action `canvas.addGLEventListener(this)`, you might think of the effect as the object passing itself as an argument to the given method. More formally, though, it is passing a *reference* to itself -- its address, as it were.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how using a method by itself without it being applied to the object affects it? E.g. why is it not theobject.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)? Also I updated a third question if you could help with that as well?

Comment: @darkphoton, you never "use a method by itself".  If you invoke an instance method without designating the object you're invoking it on, then you are invoking it on the object *performing* the invocation, exactly as if you had specified `this.` explicitly.  Most people don't like typing more than they need to do, and don't like reading noise, so they opt to leave off the `this.` in that situation.